# Chromebook dictation setting is enabled but in Google search there's an error that "Voice search has been turned off"

Tags: chromebook, voice

I would like to speak my search-phrase into Google search on my Chromebook. Dictation has been enabled in Settings and the device responds to "Hey, Google".  But when I go to Google in Chrome and tap the mic icon, there's an error message that "Voice search has been turned off". What am I missing?

EDIT: Found it in Chrome settings. Have to delete Google.com as a site that's not allowed to use the mic.

Answer (score 0):

Found it in Chrome Site Settings. Have to delete Google.com as a site that's not allowed to use the mic.